# Django - i try loader.get_template() via terminal

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm doing the [Django1.6 tutorial 03](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/)

#### And I try via terminal...

```
# python manage.py shell
>>> from django.http import HttpResponse
>>> from django.template import RequestContext, loader
>>> from polls.models import Poll
>>> 
>>> latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
>>> template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
```

#### What happened

I see the error:

```
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: polls/index.html
```

#### What I expected

**via browser works correctly** but not via terminal

I expected that it works through the terminal

The problem is inside `loader.get_template('polls/index.html')`  --- I think so:)

Through the terminal the path must be different???

But what???

Comment: When you say `via browser works correctly` do you mean you have written the entire view and template and can see them via the development server? Have you placed the `index.html` template in the `templates/poll/` folder?

Comment: Yes that's right!
I see the browser correctly and have added the template.

Answer (score 0):

if you run this from /home/users/--/Dekstop/ and put the folder polls on there and then try it what happens?

Also remember to make sure you are up to date with python. linux's python is normally out of date.

EDIT:

command to check version:

python --version

Comment: my directory is `/home/flavio/projects/mysite`

Do you think if I put everything in the `home/flavio/Desktop` folder should work?

Comment: You need a solid place to keep your projects so it may work unless the template is wrong.

Comment: Also try to do more work in a text file called "name.py" don't call it anything like random or Color else it will break python

Comment: strange. did you try it in a .py file not from terminal?

Comment: I have version 3.4 installed on the shortcut python3, already tested and did work. On the other hand, the Django documentation says that the version 1.6 works with python 2.7

Comment: emm... bug maybe? or maybe an earlyier version or 1.6